# An excel formula that aligns cells with an offset

Tags: excel

Is it possible to refer to cells with an offset as follows:

```
    A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J  

1   x1   -    -    x2   -    -    x3   -    -    X4

2

3   x1   x2   x3   X4
```

I want the cells in row three to be a formula to the cells in row1, aligning them to adjacent cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write this formula:

```
=INDEX($1:$1;1;COLUMN()*3-2)
```

Comment: awesome, took me the rest of the evening to bend this in the right form in my aweful spreadsheet, but it works like you said. thx! :)